# NodeJS extract tbz file and save to disk

Tags: node.js

Would like to know how to extract tbz file with Node JS and save to disk. Sample code would be very appreciated.

Tried with something like this:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createReadStream('/tmp.tbz');
var zip = file.pipe(zlib.createUnzip());

zip.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

zip.on("error",function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

But end up with:

```
{ [Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

Not sure I did this correctly.

Comment: Tried with zlib createUnzip, but return "errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR". I have no idea, whether I am on the right path.

Comment: If that's a bzip'ed tar file, I'm not sure zlib supports that format.  You may have to use a module like [`node-gzbz2`](https://github.com/Woodya/node-gzbz2)

Comment: Thanks.That's what confused me as well, with zlib, tar, gzbz and others. Not sure which is the proper algorithm to do so. But, eventually I found a hack to extract the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't manage to find node library for extracting the tbz file, as I test with zlib,node-tar and etc. Eventually come out with this hack using 'tar' command.

```
var util  = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('tar', ['-C','/home/tony/Desktop','-xvf', '/home/tony/Desktop/tmp.tbz']);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

I temporary accept my answer, until better one comes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `.tbz` is bzip2, therefore you can use this module: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/unbzip2-stream` to extract data.

I was able to extract a `.tbz` file like this:

```
fs.createReadStream(sourceFileName)
  .pipe(bz2())
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destinationFileName))
```